# What is the WCF correspondent for Java?

Tags: java, .net, wcf

Is there a unique service centralizer like WCF for Java where I can create and host services for different media?

---

Change:
It seems it has a different concept in the java world, is it called application server?

Comment: An application server like Glassfish or Tomcat?

Comment: What do you mean by media? The different [protocol/transport options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733769.aspx) that you get for WCF?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[JAX-WS / Metro](http://metro.java.net/)

- allows you to annotate your web service class and methods and generates a WSDL from those annotations, just like WCF.
- allows you to generate a service wsdl-first, just like WCF
- allows you to generate a web service client, just like WCF
- allows you to host your web service in any Java EE container. This is comparable to WCF's IIS hosting.
- allows you to host your web services using the `Endpoint` api. This is comparable to WCFs self-hosting.
- allows you to choose between [SOAP or Fast InfoSet](http://metro.java.net/guide/ch02.html#using-fastinfoset) over [HTTP or TCP protocols](http://metro.java.net/guide/ch09.html), like the [WCF transport options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733769.aspx). (Though I don't think it allows named pipes...)

So in many ways it corresponds to WCF. It is more focussed on Web Services than WCF is, though. Like the names say.

Answer (score 2):

I have found some blog, it is pretty old, but it explained very well about **java jax-ws and .net-wcf.**

Hope [this](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/Post/NET-WCF-vs-Java-JAX-WS-and-JAX-RS.aspx) helps..!

Answer (score 1):

The options I've found are

Netty 
http://netty.io/

Apache MINA
http://mina.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and it's pretty simple to use it's called java webservices, and it uses wsdl files like WCF and everything. refer to this: http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-hello-world-example/

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to host your `application`  locally ...For that there are several  [application  server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_server)'s like `Jboss,Glassfish,Tomcat,IBM Web sphere` ...

Comment: The jax-ws server runtime allows you to host your services too, by instantiating `Endpoint`s.